# Job Board theme with API to import job listings

Tags: api, wordpress

I'm a looking for a Job Board theme (Wordpress for example) with an API that would allow me to automatically import job listings.
Any recommendation?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Workable](https://www.workable.com). There's also a [Workable API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wrapper-for-workable-api/) plugin for WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Workscout, Wordpress theme. Not perfect, but not bad.

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining why, or by giving a summary of the main features.